# Serialize complex form to Json and deserialize it in mvc action

Tags: json, serialization, deserialization

I am trying to serialize a form to Json and post it with $.post to MVC action and deserialize it to model. it work with simple forms(forms with non-complex properties). but when I have complex properties or arrays it dosn't work.

Here is models:

```
 public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Family { get; set; }

    public Contact Contact { get; set; }

}

public class Contact
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Tel { get; set; }
}
```

In view I use this Js function to serialize model:

```
function serializeForm() {

    return JSON.stringify($("#myForm").serializeObject());

}
```

With this Jquery command I post it to action

```
     $.post(url, { person: serializeForm() },
          function (data) {

          }
        );
```

And in action I use of Newtonsoft helper for deserialize the posted string

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditPerson(string person)
    {

        var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(person);

        return null;
    }
```

The "Contact" property is null after deserialization.
I try JavaScriptSerializer for deserialize but it dosn't work.
Is there a way to serialize complex form to json and deserialize it in action with all arrays and objects?

Comment: What does your controller post action look like?

Comment: Action is very simple, it decorated with a [HttpPost] attribute.